# Can I add new property to scope passed to link function in directive?

Tags: angularjs-directive

Can I add new property to scope passed to link function in directive?

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
scope.addNewfunction(){
   scope.apply(function(){   
       scope.property = value; // assign value to scope property
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add properties to the scope in the link function, but what you're doing in your example is calling a function on the scope.

If you want to add a property, simple do:

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    scope.property = value;
}
```

If you want to add a function to the scope, simple do:

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    scope.newFunction = function() {
        scope.property = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i add property dynamically on function call?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't you? That's exactly what my second example does. scope is just an object, and you can put new properties on it whenever you like.